# How do i declare array for the lookup column using jquery

Tags: jquery, lookup-column

How do i declare array for the lookup column using jquery. I have a column whose values should be declared as array. so that my requirements get it complete.

I need that ID for every values to get through the req.

i mean, first value should be a[0] and then a[1]....

i know it is just simple. It is not a  multiple selection field.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking how to get the values and IDs associated with a lookup column from a select box on a SharePoint page? Or something else?

Comment: Clarify your question. Do you mean you need to get all the items in a select list into an array? Do you need the values or the display names or both?

Comment: I need to know...how to declare an array first.... I am hanging there itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not multiple selection and just like dropdown field. I used the following but failed

```
$("#ctl00_m_g__ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup").change(function(){ 
   var v1=$("#ctl00_m_g__ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup").val();
   alert(v1[i]);
});
```

Comment: is this syntax correct..or else help me by finding the syntax

Comment: v1 will in this case contain the value, not an array

Comment: And by the way, this is not really an answer and should be added to your original question